# How to compute this integral over a small ball?

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

$$\int_{{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}<1}x^2dxdy$$

I only know that $$z=(x, y)^T$$ is a small, directional vector.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not sure why $z$ would help here, but one way would be to do this directly, i.e.
$$
\int_{x=-1}^{x=1} \int_{y = -\sqrt{1-x^2}}^{y = \sqrt{1-x^2}} x^2 dy dx
 = \int_{x=-1}^{x=1}
      \left[ \int_{y = -\sqrt{1-x^2}}^{y = \sqrt{1-x^2}} dy \right] 
      x^2 dx
 = 2 \int_{-1}^1 x^2 \sqrt{1-x^2} dx
$$
It may be easier to switch to polar
$$
\int_0^1 \int_0^{2\pi} \left(r^2 \cos^2 \theta\right) rdr d\theta
 = \left(\int_0^1 r^3 dr\right) \left( \int_0^{2\pi} \cos^2 \theta d\theta \right)
$$

Can you finish?

Comment: So is it just pi/4? Thank you.

Comment: @n.mathfreak indeed, this is correct